# Gauss-Green cubature in 2d

Tags: numerical-methods, physics

Hello friends of maths,

I've given an arbitrary polygonal cross section (in cartesian coordinates $y$ and $z$). On this cross section, there acts an arbitrary stress-field $\sigma = f(y,z)$ as integrable function of $y$ and $z$.

Now I need to numerically determine the momentum ($M_y$ and $M_z$) as well as the axial force $N_x$ that results from the stress-field. Therefore, I read about the Gauss-Green cubature in a [recent published PhD-thesis](http://openlib.tugraz.at/download.php?id=56530f5c82191&location=browse), what sounds quite practicable (see pp 89-91).
Unfortunately in this thesis the acting stress-field mainly results from biaxial bending. This means that it is possible to transform the whole coordinate sytsem into a principal coordinate system what simplifies the whole procedure.

So, does anybody know if (and how) it is possible to use the Gauss-Green cubature for arbitrary polygonal cross-sections under arbitrary stress-fields? How do the formulas given in this thesis (and that I summerized below and commented for the "non-german-speakers") have to be adapted?

Thank you in advance for any help!

---

(p. 89): The Gaussian cubature is given by
$$
\int_a^bf(x)~\text{d}x \approx \frac{b-a}{2}\cdot\sum_{g=1}^n c_{\text{n},g}\cdot f\biggl(\frac{(b-a)\cdot r_{\text{n},g}+b+a}{2}\biggr)
$$
where $n$ is the number of integration points; $c_{n,g}$ are the position of the integration points in the interval $[-1;1]$ and $r_{n,g}$ are the weights of the integration points in $[-1;1]$.

(p. 99): 
[image: Gauss-Cubature]

If this cubature is combined with [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) it is more suitable to transform the coordinate system to a principal coordinate system ($\eta, \zeta$). Then the stress only depends on a coordinate ($\sigma = f(\zeta))$. [<<-- This is actually not possible in my problem].
Then, each part of the polygon has to be calculated seperately and afterwards summerized, to get the resulting forces:

$$
N_{x,pi} = \sum_{g=1}^n (\eta_\text{A}+\Delta\eta\cdot\lambda_{n,g})\cdot\Delta\zeta\cdot\sigma(\varepsilon(\lambda_{n,g}))\cdot c_{n,g}
$$
$$
M_{\eta,pi} = \sum_{g=1}^n (\eta_\text{A}+\Delta\eta\cdot\lambda_{n,g})\cdot(\zeta_\text{A}+\Delta\zeta\cdot\lambda_{n,g})\cdot\Delta\zeta\cdot\sigma(\varepsilon(\lambda_{n,g}))\cdot c_{n,g}
$$
$$
M_{\zeta,pi} = \sum_{g=1}^n-\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\eta_\text{A}+\Delta\eta\cdot\lambda_{n,g})^2\cdot\Delta\zeta\cdot\sigma(\varepsilon(\lambda_{n,g}))\cdot c_{n,g}
$$
with $\lambda_{n,g}=\frac{1+r_{n,g}}{2}$ for [0;1]

And finally, the force-vector results from:
$$
\vec s = \begin{Bmatrix}
           N_x \\
           M_\eta \\
           M_\zeta
         \end{Bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_\text{p}}\begin{Bmatrix}
           N_{x,p_i} \\
           M_{\eta,p_i} \\
           M_{\zeta,p_i}
         \end{Bmatrix}
$$
... and the momentums $M_y$ and $M_z$ result from back-transformation to the original coordinate system.